# Please help. I can't boot my new Ubuntu install with the following results from Boot Info Script

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

Hi all I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried all the ways that I could find to make it boot but when ever I get my Live Stick out of the laptop it loads the UEFI by default. I've tried the Boot-Repair tool but I keep receiving the`Please close all your package managers (Software Center, Update Manager, Synaptic, ...) Then try again.` I've tried every other command line method I've found online and nothing seems to work. I understand that the Boot Info Script might be of help in this situation but I'm not sure how to make use of if.

Please see it below:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 85 for .
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32784 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048   306,268,159   306,266,112   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         306,268,160   307,202,047       933,888   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         512,002,048 1,953,523,711 1,441,521,664   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         307,204,094   512,002,047   204,797,954   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         307,204,096   323,981,311    16,777,216  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6         492,550,144   502,278,143     9,728,000  83 Linux
/dev/sda7         502,280,192   512,002,047     9,721,856  83 Linux
/dev/sda8    *    491,524,096   492,537,855     1,013,760  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda9         323,983,360   491,506,797   167,523,438  83 Linux


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.4 GiB, 15479597056 bytes, 30233588 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048    30,233,587    30,231,540   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        0E0AA5550AA53B1B                       ntfs       
/dev/sda2        50FC56BCFC569C52                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        A0F06BABF06B85FE                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        a4492130-853f-42a8-afd1-f9b742ba8a5f   swap       
/dev/sda6        4979b753-1781-4c49-ba58-dd90c0d32b4f   ext4       
/dev/sda7        c1ca21c9-fa0d-450a-9203-0bc6df958ecd   ext4       
/dev/sda8        BE69-EB89                              vfat       
/dev/sda9        6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        18C4-2315                              vfat       UBUNTU 18_0

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda9/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos9'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=10
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-advanced-6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-recovery-6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda9/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=6e375bc4-0e80-48ad-a742-acc0592bd785 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda8 during installation
#UUID=BE69-EB89  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /tmp was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c1ca21c9-fa0d-450a-9203-0bc6df958ecd /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=4979b753-1781-4c49-ba58-dd90c0d32b4f /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a4492130-853f-42a8-afd1-f9b742ba8a5f none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda9: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-09wCNLsG/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-09wCNLsG/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-09wCNLsG/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```